# CRM 2011 Filtering view on related record type

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to create a new view for the activities entity. My aim was to show only the activities that were related to a record of a certain type eg account. But when i was creating it i saw that aside from saying if it contains data or not, and for specific records, there isnt an option for entity type.

I can understand why this isnt an option in the list, as its not really something people would need to do, but is this possible at all?

Thanks

Comment: I've provided an answer but I'm not sure I understand the last part of your question. Where isn't there an option for entity type?

Comment: As @Spencerooni mentioned, if you use the related entities to connect to the `Account` entity, the `FetchXml` will use an inner join linking to `Accounts` that will enforce your entity type condition. You can do this for any other related entity as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Advanced Find and specify the following criteria:

- Look for: Activities
- Related > Regarding (Account)

This will get you all activities which are related to an account.

Comment: Ah yeah, i see that now, can this be applied to a system view or is it just for advanced finds?

Comment: @jimminybob When in Advanced Find, you can save the View and make it the default for an entity via: Customizations > Soluton > Entities > Account > Views. Is that what you mean?